# Finding pairwise labels for the minimum value from a distance matrix dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance-matrix

I have a `scipy` `distance_matrix` as a `dataframe`.

**How do I extract the minimum value (excluding 0.00) per row along with the associated (row,column) labels for that values from a dataframe?**

For example:

The `min` for the first row would be `[0.012885,'king','boy']`

The `min` for the second row would be `[2.826742,'wise','bananas']`

Code for `DataFrame`:

```py
import scipy
...
 df = pd.DataFrame(scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(w2v_df[['x1', 'x2']], 
                                                          w2v_df[['x1', 'x2']]),
                           index=w2v_df['word'],
                           columns=w2v_df['word'])
print(df)
print(df.size)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
word            king       wise      queen  ...       kind        man        boy
word                                        ...                                 
king        0.000000   7.917140  10.963772  ...   5.811759   3.180582   0.012885
wise        7.917140   0.000000   6.642557  ...  10.990575   9.957878   7.908536
queen      10.963772   6.642557   0.000000  ...  10.347096  11.126121  10.951130
trees       9.954951   3.937842   2.917539  ...  10.940161  10.948519   9.943392
lab         7.437203  11.811392  10.148030  ...   1.716404   4.612150   7.429358
prince      3.180829   9.958469  11.126762  ...   2.897802   0.000654   3.177194
monkeys    10.007491   3.958035   2.926149  ...  10.995299  11.004550   9.995942
girl        5.820748   5.026462   5.153798  ...   6.336225   6.244742   5.808014
woman      10.663214   8.143587   2.350959  ...   8.843283  10.155728  10.650332
princess    5.204497   5.744348   5.894201  ...   5.439997   5.356606   5.191617
cat         3.033364   5.678351  10.397241  ...   8.359144   6.077646   3.031699
dinosaurs   5.745362   6.422390   5.683175  ...   5.075057   5.442950   5.732531
person      9.421978  10.901532   7.192433  ...   5.081030   7.477618   9.410744
bananas     5.238502   2.826742   8.147972  ...   9.239873   7.668165   5.231329
partner     7.752175  10.135952   7.572307  ...   3.468261   5.742199   7.741316
rat         8.830544   8.633246   4.739600  ...   6.113317   7.734904   8.818027
kind        5.811759  10.990575  10.347096  ...   0.000000   2.897668   5.804801
man         3.180582   9.957878  11.126121  ...   2.897668   0.000000   3.176944
boy         0.012885   7.908536  10.951130  ...   5.804801   3.176944   0.000000

[19 rows x 19 columns]
```

I have tried the following (still need to append associated values):

```py
df1 = df[all_results != 0]
df1.idxmin()
print(df1.idxmin())
```

out:

```
word
trees          monkeys
rat              trees
person         partner
monkeys          trees
king               boy
girl             queen
princess         woman
dinosaurs         wise
lab               kind
man             prince
boy               king
woman            queen
prince             man
wise         dinosaurs
partner         person
queen            woman
bananas         person
cat           princess
kind               lab
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that distance matrix are symmetrics. so you can just use a `dataframe.sort_value(by='king')` per example for every row. and take with `.iloc[:,1]`. Or you can use just min function and stock it in a list.

I did this and works good for a little dataframe that looks like yours.

```
     df = df.replace(0,99999) /// # OR df.replace(0,999,inplace = True)
     #get the min for per example the king
     min_king = df.king.min()
     [min_king,'king', df[df['king']==min_king].index.values[0]]
```

Then do a loop over the block to get all the index